# request.user.is_authenticated returning false even though logged in

Tags: python, django

In the HTML template, request.user.is_authenticated keeps returning nothing, and it keeps acting like I have never logged in. I have logged in...

This is Home Views.py, after it logged in, it returns to home.html

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    print("USER?: " + str(request.user))
    print(request.user.is_authenticated)
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render_to_response('index.html')
    return render_to_response('home.html', request)
```

This is Account Views.py

```
def log_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.cleaned_data['username']
            pword = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username = user, password = pword)
            if user is not None:
                # return render(, 'home.html')
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
            else:
                return render(request, 'login.html', { 'logform': form, 'error': True})
    else:
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        else:
            form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', { 'logform':form,})
```

This is home.html document:

```
    {{ user.username }}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
    {% endif %}
```

`{{ user.username }}` does not show anything if I put it out the if/else statement. However, in login function, I print out the `user.is_authenticated` it shows my username printed and logged in. Also, in HTML document, it goes to else if I logged in or not logged in.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Before you run `request.user.is_authenticated()` please print `request.user`. Check if it's `AnonymousUser ` or not. Are you using any cookies?

Comment: Yes I am using cookies. Before login in, it prints out `AnonymousUser`. After it's logged in, it print's out: `JohnJoe`.

Comment: I believe it's about cookies. If you are setting cookies, and if they contain special chars like `[`, `]` it causes django to crash reading some of cookies. I advice you to base64 encode such cookies.

Comment: Please show the view that is rendering that template.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have updated the post, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using a RequestContext to render the template, so context processors are not run and `user` is not added to the context.

You can see from the example of the `log_in` view that you should be using `render(request, ...)` rather than `render_to_response(...)`; that render shortcut creates a RequestContext for you.

Comment: In my log_in in account.views, I have not use render_response?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that question.

Comment: You mentioned that, in my log_in, you said, I should be using render(request...) not render_response(...), and I have no use any render_response(....)... It would be great if you can like show the code or the fixes?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said `render_to_response`. Regardless, you should be using `render` instead, like you are doing in log_in.